# ORA-00904 when for inner joining same table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, table-alias

My query is :

```
select right.* from Table1 JOIN Table1 right on (right.field1 = left.field1)
```

I need to expand this query even more with where clause.
But this itself is throwing, *ORA-00904 : invalid identifier* error.

Comment: `right` and `left` are reserved keywords you need to find different aliases (and you did not actually define the alias `left`)

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Right` and `Left`  are reserved keywords name for right and left join

change `right` and `left` to some other alias name.